# How to solve Leaflet Popup overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I leave the popups open all the time and whatever I do in the popups always come on top of each other. How can I solve this as in the picture.

```
  marker.on('click',  function (event) {
  var container = $('<div>DENEME<div/>');
  container.html("This is a linkasd <a href='#' class='smallPolygonLink'>Click me</a>.");
  container.append($('<span class="bold">').text(" :)"))
  marker.bindPopup(container[0], { permanent: true, autoClose: false, autoPan: true, closeOnClick: false, offset: [0, 20] });                          
  });
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want it to do? Close the popup behind? Position the popups so they aren't overlapping?

Comment: I want the windows to not overlap